# How to get message count of mac messages app in applescript *Not Mail*

Tags: scripting, applescript, message

I am trying to make a script that returns the amount of unread messages in messages app on a mac, I know the code for mail but can't figure this problem out.

Comment: I doubt this is possible at all because none of the relevant classes has a `unread` property

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Check some of the Apple Scripts [On this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125886/why-does-messages-on-osx-always-show-unread-messages)

Specifically, this one looked promising although it didn't work for me:

> tell application "Messages" to "clear unread messages"

You should be able to:

1. Open Script Editor
2. Copy the above script into it
3. Click the Run icon to run the script